# Basis and dimensions example

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Every basis of $\mathbb R^6$ can not be reduced to a basis of $5$-dimensional  subspace of $\mathbb R^6$ by removing one vector . Can anyone give an example for that?

Comment: It is a rather confusing wording and I can't understand what you really want to ask. Any basis of $\;\Bbb R^6;$ can be made a basis of some subspace of dimension $\;5\;% of it by merely deleting one vector. Now, upon be given a specific, particula subspace of dimension $\;5\;$  it is true that not from any basis we can delete an element and remain with a basis of it. Which one is it?

Comment: If S is a 5−5dimensional subspace of R^6.Is it true that every basis of R^6 can be reduced to a basis of S by removing one vector ? If not is there any example ? If yes then how to prove ?

Comment: Not "every basis", obviously. As a simple example, consider the standard basis $ (1, 0) $, $ (0, 1) $ for $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ and try to obtain the subspace spanned by $ (1, 1) $. The argument generalizes easily to your case. On the other hand, there is a basis of $ \mathbb{R}^6 $ such that deleting an element from it will give you a set that spans your subspace, in other words, any linearly independent set can be extended to a basis.

Comment: That means the statement is not true in general and we have to give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example the basis of $\;\Bbb R^6\;$

$$S:=\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

and take the $\;5\,-$ dimensional subspace

$$W:=\left\{\;\;\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\\a\\b\end{pmatrix}\;:\;\;x=0\right\}$$

Comment: What is the basis of $W$ then ??

Comment: @Shona There is no **the** basis of a space, in general. There is *some* basis. You can do it by yourself, I think:  all the coordinates from the second to the sixth are free for you to choose, but **all** the elements must have, by definition, the first coordinate equal to zero.

Comment: (0,y,z,w,a,b)= (y-z)(0,1,0,0,0,0)+(z-w)(0,1,1,0,0,0)+(w-a)(0,1,1,1,0,0)+(a-b)(0,1,1,1,1,0)+b(0,1,1,1,1,1)

Comment: @Shona For example, yes: the five coordinate vectors you wrote area basis for $\;W\;$

Comment: And these are reduced from S which is a basis of R^6

Comment: @Shona No, they are not. The given basis of $\;\Bbb R^6\;$ has all its elements with first coordinate different from zero.

Comment: But when we made the first coordinate zero then it is a basis of W

Comment: @Shona The elements of the particular base you chose for $\;W\;$ are **not** part of the original basis I gave for $\;\Bbb R^6\;$, and this shows: when a basis for the bigger space is given, **not always** it is possible to produce *from it* a basis for the smaller subspace, or: not always you can choose elements from a base of the bigger space that will be a basis for the smaller one.

Comment: Ok now i understand , the elements of S all have firrst xoordinate non-zero whereas any basis for W must have the first coordinate zero , right

Comment: @Shona Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you so much Joanpemo for helping 

Comment: @Shona My pleasure. It is customary to upvote all the answers you found helpful and, eventually, *to accept* the one that you liked the most. But, of course, only if you want to. Points don't really matter much here.

Comment: I do but at night when i go through everythinģ again .. thank you for reminding and cannot forget to upvote yours cuz u  helped so much ..